# How do you configure the Password Memory on the F5 Big IP?

Tags: f5

I'm trying to find out what the command line option is to set the password memory of an F5 BIG IP. I know Password Memory can be set from the GUI but I'm not sure how it is done using the tmsh?

I reviewed the online documentation of F5, but this command wasn't listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Last login: Mon Nov 24 11:12:09 2014 from 1.1.1.1
>
> bp>!bash
>
> [JH@F5:Standby] ~ # tmsh
>
> JH@F5(Standby)(tmos)# modify auth password-policy password-memory ?
>
> Specifies the number of passwords that the BIG-IP system will remember for each user. A user will not be able to set their password
>   to one of these passwords. The default value is 0 (zero).

If you look under the section for password-policy in the link below, you'll find password-memory in the available commands.

http://rekrowten.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/f5-tmos-configuration-part-1/